# How to update more than one column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL which I am using for updating many rows at the same time using a complex case condition. Currently, I am setting 2 column using the same CASE condition.

For example, I need to do something like:

```
UPDATE  MyTable
SET([MyColumn1], [MyColumn2]) = ('','')
```

What I am doing now is:

```
UPDATE  MyTable
SET [MyColumn1] = COMPLEX CASE RETURN STRING,
    [MyColumn2] = 100% SAME COMPLEX CASE RETURN A Different STRING
```

I tried but getting error. Is this is possible in SQL SERVER?

It is supported in IBM Db, http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls919.htm
But it seems there is no support in SQL Server

Comment: It would be better if you share the Complex Case that is returning a string

Comment: what is the error u getting ?
try executing the cases separately to see where the error actually lies

Comment: need additional details about the error and complex case. I hope you are aware of the update statement syntax.

Comment: @Murtaza, I think it is not supported in SQL SERVER but supported by some other vendors, see question edit

Comment: @user960567 - then you are using a wrong syntax buddy. You will need to use the syntax supported by SQL rather than Informix SQL

Answer (score 2):

Update command syntax is:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   update mytable
     SET [MyColumn1] = COMPLEX CASE RETURN STRING,
        [MyColumn2] = 100% SAME COMPLEX CASE RETURN A Different STRING
     WHERE some_column=some_value;// please have the where condition
```

then only we can update the corresponding raw.

updating means we are changing some existing values so we need to provide the location where we want this change,for that we can use the where condition..
example
update author

```
set name="onv kurup"
set book="oralude"
where authorid=112;
```

**if we are not giving the where condition all the data of the table will be get updated with same value in the update query we have given**

Answer (score -1):

After searching a lot, I have found the answer,

```
update table1
set col1 = a.col1, col2 = a.col2, col3 = a.col3 from
table1 as a Join on tablefunction
where table1.col1 <expression>
```

http://geekswithblogs.net/phoenix/archive/2009/10/13/update-multiple-columns-on-sql-server.aspx